# Which design pattern to use for an email bounce-handler?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I wrote an email bounce handler class (in PHP) which was initially only for parsing well-formatted RFC compliant email bounce messages.  However, as time went by I kept adding more and more methods to handle non-compliant bounce messages, which you could say are a different "type" of bounce.  Then, in response to a customer's request, I added support for ARF messages, which are a 3rd type of bounce.  AND, of course, there are now non-compliant ARF messages floating around, so I had to add a parser for that too.

So, now the class handles four bounce types:

1. RFC compliant
2. RFC non-compliant
3. ARF compliant
4. ARF non-compliant

Having several types of messages means that I had to put a "text sniffer" into the  initialization function, which calls the appropriate internal parsing functions, collates the results and returns it.  That part is important because there needs to be a single public method that receives any email text and returns a formatted array (is_a_bounce=yes/no, is_an_ARF=yes/no, RFC code, rejected-recipient email address), like this:

```
$arrayResult = $bounceHandler->parse($raw_email_text);
```

Problem, the class is messy / overcrowded, and I would like to refactor it into a more formal and correct OOP design pattern.

- Which design pattern would you recommend?
- Any PHP examples or articles / blogs?

thanks in advance

Comment: You've been very badly taught. You should never pick a pattern for your problem then try to make your code fit - patterns describe what the code you have written is.

Comment: This is not quite true, you should always consider multiple strategies to solve a problem before you actually solve it. Patterns exist to help guide development, not to describe it.

Comment: you are not showing the class, so it's hard to give anything but general suggestions. Start here: http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are essentially describing a class that abstracts how a bounce is handled and has different implementations for handling different bounces. This matches the description of the Bridge design pattern.

Essentially you will have an Abstraction class that offers an interface ( in this case the function parse($raw_email_text) ) and decides what Handler implementation to use after it has "sniffed" the message.

You can create an Interface for the Handler Implementation allowing you to extend the available alternative implementations as new features are required. You can also ensure the Abstraction implements that same interface, allowing the user to use an implementation instead of the abstraction in cases where he knows the type of the message.